# How to get constant facecolor for matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have an array with `np.nan`s inside it to effectively mask out portions of a plot.
The array that I want to plot is

```
a = np.array([
    [1, np.nan, 1, np.nan],
    [1, np.nan, 1, np.nan],
    [1, np.nan, 1, np.nan],
    [1, np.nan, 1, np.nan],
])
```

When i plot `a` using

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.pcolormesh(a)
```

[image]

The color of the plot is according to the default color map. But suppose I want the plot to be of a constant color, and still maintain it's masking, I try the following

```
plt.pcolormesh(a, color='r')
```

[image]

---

How can I specify the a constant color for the plot in a way that I do not have to create custom color maps?

Comment: What exactly do you want?  8 purple squares and 2 white rectangles?

Comment: `pcolormesh` seems to always use a colormap for the face colors. So you'll need something like `plt.pcolormesh(a, cmap=matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(['crimson']))` for a constant color.

Comment: @JohanC thanks for the workaround. do you know where I can find a list of the available `ListedColormap`s?

Comment: @DanielF It is not that the white rectangles are white, they are masked out via the `np.nan`. I am seeking a uniform color for the non-masked out values

Comment: The standard list of [css4 color names](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/gallery/color/named_colors.html), an extended list of [xkcd colors](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/tutorials/colors/colors.html#xkcd-v-x11-css4), many ways to [specify colors](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/tutorials/colors/colors.html#specifying-colors)